# migrating users from one apk to another

Tags: android, merge, migration

We have an app (A1) with significant number of users still active, but we no longer plan to support the app. Now we have another smaller app (A2), which is similar to A1.

Is there any way that when users from A1 update their app from the Play Store that they get A2? Basically, we want to migrate users from A1 to A2.

Of note, the package names are different.

Comment: If you use the same package name and incremented version code, and upload into the same project in play store, the users will get the newer apk as the update to the old apk.

Answer (score 0):

It All depends upon the database. You should research about the database you are using for your app to store users data. Connect the same database to your new app or just copy the all users data from A1's Database to the A2's Database, and implementation for all this depends on your database implementation.

Share your more information about your database, this may help you to get a answer.
You could do this implementation maybe in another language like JavaScript etc. Then in A2 use the same implementations ti read and write the data in users.

**But beware that you copy data using the same database structure as you used in A1's Database**

Comment: thank you for your detailed response but how would merging db help in users on A1 to get A2. I didn't explain the requirements clear enough it seems. Think of it as instagram & snapchat (say, I own both!) - i plan to shut instagram down but I want the users of instagram to get upgraded to snapchat and I also want to maintain just one package in future - snapchat. So I want to create an update (for instagram users) and when they update instagram, they get updated to snapchat.